# Why does gnome-control-center have png images for a fingerprint reader? Does it have one and can I use it?

Tags: fingerprint-reader, gnome-control-center

So I was randomly looking at images on my computer and I found these in `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/pixmaps`:

[image]

I didn't think Ubuntu had any built in fingerprint reader support. So why are these here and did I miss something? I haven't installed any fingerprint reader related packages that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Those are there when you need them. You don't need a fingerprint reader for those images being there at all, when you get a fingerprint reader the images don't need to be downloaded and installed.

Those images are provided by the `gnome-control-center-data` which provides non-architecture dependant files needed for Gnome Control Center to work. The fact that the images are there doesn't mean that you have a fingerprint reader, but that your system will be ready the very moment you install one.

Comment: Hmm. Got any sources by any chance? Seems a bit odd to me, especially since there isn't a whole lot of software out there that would ever even use this.

Comment: @Seth long description of the package: "This package contains data files (icons, pixmaps, locales files) needed by the configuration applets in the gnome-control-center package."

Comment: Then maybe there's an applet that uses these? Per the answer below, I've done some Googeling and it does appear that the default gnome settings manager *does* support something to do with fingerprint reading.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME does, in fact, have "built-in" fingerprint reader support.

See [this help thread from gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/session-fingerprint.html.en).

Comment: I mainly use Unity, but when I log in with Gnome I don't still don't see any fingerprint options..

Comment: @Seth I see. Just to be clear, you did enable fingerprint login as the article above mentions?

Comment: No I did not, because I can't find anything related to fingerprints in the place it said to look.

Comment: Upon using my Google fu, it appears that this was an older gnome feature that has since been removed.